# cpu and memory usage in heroku with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

How do I see the cpu and memory usage of my app in heroku with ruby.
Is there something like "top" command of ubuntu which gives me the memory and cpu utilization in it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to activate the free Newrelic add-on: https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic It does not only give you memory and cpu information, but many insight into your app: https://newrelic.com/application-monitoring/features

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check this info, I copy&paste the main info of this utility, take into account it is an addon:

> This Heroku Labs log-runtime-metrics feature adds experimental support
>   for enabling visibility into load and memory usage for running dynos.
>   Per-dyno stats on memory use, swap use, and load average are inserted
>   into the app’s log stream where they can be seen via heroku logs
>   --tail, used for graphs or alerting via an add-on which consumes app logs, or sent to a log drain. There is no cost incurred by enabling
>   this feature.

[log-runtime-metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an app on Heroku with two or more dynos, then you have access to application metrics via the Heroku dashboard

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/metrics

Otherwise, New Relic or some of the other addons for Heroku will give you this kind of information

https://addons.heroku.com/?q=Monitor